# Is there solution to fix the error in transformers while paraphrasing text

Tags: python-3.x

```
import torch
from transformers import PegasusForConditionalGeneration, PegasusTokenizer

model_name = 'tuner007/pegasus_paraphrase'
torch_device = 'cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu'
tokenizer = PegasusTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = PegasusForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained(model_name).to(torch_device)

def get_response(input_text,num_return_sequences):
  # batch = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch([input_text],truncation=True,padding='longest',max_length=60, return_tensors="pt").to(torch_device)
  with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    tokenized_text = tokenizer(input_text, truncation=True, padding='longest', max_length=60, return_tensors="pt")
    batch = tokenized_text.to(torch_device)
    translated = model.generate(**batch,max_length=60,num_beams=10, num_return_sequences=num_return_sequences, temperature=1.5)
    tgt_text = tokenizer.batch_decode(translated, skip_special_tokens=True)
    return tgt_text

text = "In this video, I will be showing you how to build a stock price web application in Python using the Streamlit and yfinance library."
get_response(text, 5)
```

Error:

> FutureWarning:
> `prepare_seq2seq_batch` is deprecated and will be removed in version 5 of HuggingFace Transformers. Use the regular
> `__call__` method to prepare your inputs and the tokenizer under the `as_target_tokenizer` context manager to prepare
> your targets.

Kindly help to fix this error

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unclear prepare_seq2seq_batch deprecation](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/12622#issuecomment-918981618)

Comment: I am not able to identify where to add this----> with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    tokenized_text = tokenizer(text, return_tensors='pt') in code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/12622#issuecomment-918981618), replace

```
batch = tokenizer.prepare_seq2seq_batch([input_text],truncation=True,padding='longest',max_length=60, return_tensors="pt").to(torch_device)
```

with

```
with tokenizer.as_target_tokenizer():
    tokenized_text = tokenizer(input_text, truncation=True,padding='longest',max_length=60, return_tensors="pt")
    batch = tokenized_text.to(torch_device)
```

Comment: Kindly check the code modified above its not returning nothing "return tgt_text"

Comment: Unindent two spaces from lines 13 until 16 and see if it gives an error.

Comment: The error has gone but its not returning tgt_text

Comment: What was the error that appeared? Is it returning None?

Comment: No its not returning None, It is returning empty. The error that appered was FutureWarning: prepare_seq2seq_batch,